# Rebind JS files after change HTML using AJAX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a ASP.NET CORE MVC project that change main layout using AJAX.
Below is simple code snippet of my project

_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/datatables.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</head>
<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini layout-fixed">
    <div id="divMain">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Home > Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home";
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
</div>
```

UserController.cs

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

User > Index.cshtml

```
<div class="text-center">
    <h1>User</h1>
    <button type="button" class="datatable-search">Search</button>
</div>
```

site.js

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "/User/Index",
    
     success: function (response) {
         $("#divMain").html(response);
     },
     error: function (error) { }
 });
```

datatables.js

```
$(."datatable-search").on("click", function (e) {
    alert("test");
});
```

After change "divMain" to "User" html with AJAX, the "Search" button in User cannot trigger class "datatable-search" on click event

Is there any method to rebind the JS files in _Layout.cshtml?

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net core by default The file **_ViewStart** specifies that all views will use the **_Layout** layout. So your site.js in _Layout causes the duplicated calling of index and cannot run correctly and you don't need to add again. Here is a code sample modified.

**1 _Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/WebApplication2.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/datatables.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</head>
<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini layout-fixed">
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="User" asp-action="Index">User Index</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="divMain">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**2 Home/Index.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
</div>
```

**3** Remove the code of **site.js**

**4 datatable.js**

```
$(document).on("click", ".datatable-search", function (e) {
    alert("test");
});
```

[image]

Click on the nav-link and get your user index page , and test the onclick event.

[image]